# Mixing both for expressions using shape keys

Tags: edit-mode, shape-keys

I want the eyes to be wide at the same time. The shape key is first used to shape the eye hole, then the shape key is used again to shape the eyeballs. However, I do not know how to fix it. Is there a way to make both eyes wide at the same time? Make sure you add an explanation to help me better understand the picture/gif[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably better to use bones rather than shapekeys but you can use a bone in order to control both the 2 shapekeys at the same time, for example:

Create a bone that will be your shape key controller. Select your object, right click on the shape key Value and *Add Driver*:

[image]

Open the *Drivers* editor, unfold the tracks on the left, select the *Value* track, press <kbd>N</kbd> to open the right panel, click on the *Drivers* tab, choose *Type > Averaged Value*, as *Object* select the armature and then  as *Bone* select the controller bone, choose *Type > X Location* (or whatever axis you want to move your bones) and *Space > Local Space*:

[image]

Do the same for the other object, now when you move the bone it triggers the shape keys:

[image]